# What's it called? Indicating no exceptions to the rule

Tags: terminology, semantics, pragmatics

In my study of an ancient language, I’m seeing certain phrasing that, in a **prescription** of proper behavior, means emphatically: **“without exception!”** My question is: Do linguists have a label for this phenomenon?

These cases arise in categorical *negative polarity* or *conditional* environments. The phrasing in question involves either **marked word order**, or a **doubling of the indefinite-pronoun-like term**. By using this more elaborate or unusual wording, it’s as if the speaker is saying, “This applies to everyone — including you!”

Below are 4 examples, which are my paraphrased renderings into English — a language where this kind of message is conveyed **lexically** rather than **grammatically**. To highlight the markedness involved, I pair each example with a simpler version of the utterance. On its face, the latter is equally categorical — yet somehow does not suffice.

1. “Don’t tell anyone **at all** about this conversation, or you will die.”
   *versus*
   “Don’t tell anyone about this conversation.…”
2. “Not **a single solitary** one of you shall act without my say-so.”
   *versus*
   “None of you shall act without my say-so.”
3. “**Absolutely** no one should bring a gift.”
   *versus*
   “No one should bring a gift.”
4. “If anyone **at all** slaughters an ox in the camp…”
   *versus*
   “If anyone slaughters an ox in the camp…”

Presumably this phenomenon has been studied in English — but what is it called?

Comment: Such a phenomenon would probably be named after the morpheme or other characteristic phenomenon or characteristic that marked it, rather than a semantic equivalent.